# WHERE clause converting INT to DATETIME

Tags: postgresql, datetime, date-format, date

Looking for advice on how to match two differing column types:

I have two tables: `RT-A` and `DA-B`.

Under both tables there is a column named `DeliveryDate`, but the individual tables use differing column types; one `time without timezone` and the other `numeric`.

Example: in the DA-A table the DeliveryDate column reads: `"02:00:00"`
Example: in the RT-A table the DeliveryDate column reads, `"2"`.

What is the correct expression in the `WHERE` clause of an SQL statement to join rows where they equal each other?
Plain equality obviously does not work With the current design:

```
"DA-A"."DeliveryHour" = "RT-A"."DeliveryHour"
```

This is how I have been writing the SQL, but it seems to be terrible in form:

```
WHERE
  "DA-A"."DeliveryHour" = '2:00:00' AND 
  "RT-A"."DeliveryHour" = '2'
```

Comment: Do you want the two columns to just `equal each other` or to equal `2` / `2:00:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing Postgres documentation: [Date/Time Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

How do you like this?

```
WHERE date_part('hour', "DA-A"."DeliveryHour") = "RT-A"."DeliveryHour"
```

Comment: `date_part()` is the Postgres function that implements the standard SQL `extract()`. Same thing.

Comment: @DW: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

- To join all rows that "equal" each other:

```
WHERE "DA-A"."DeliveryHour"
    = '0:0'::time + "RT-A"."DeliveryHour" * interval '1h'
```

Or

```
WHERE EXTRACT(hour FROM "DA-A"."DeliveryHour")::numeric
    = "RT-A"."DeliveryHour"
```

One or the other may be favorable to keep *one* side [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable) when you want to use an index in a query on one or the other side.

- For the case where you are only interested in  `2` / `2:00:00`, your explicit expressions may be the best choice, since *both* expressions are sargable.